# Remote Link Ajax Struts

Tags: ajax, struts

In my menu.jsp:

```
 <s:url id="ajaxTest" value="addCustoInfo"/>
 <sx:a id="link3" href="%{ajaxTest}" targets="main-content">
    Update Content
 </sx:a>
```

in my struts:

```
 <action name="addCustoInfo" method="renderAddCustomerInfo"
         class="customerInfoAction">
    <result name="success">/page/addCustoInfo.jsp</result>
    <result name="empty">/page/addCustoType.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

in my CustomerAction:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public String renderAddCustomerInfo(){
    this.listCustomerType = daoManager.listCustomerType();
    if(this.listCustomerType.size() <= 0){
        this.session.put("error", "Empty customer type.");
        return "empty";
    }else{
        this.customerInfo = new CustomerInfo();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

in addCustoInfo.jsp:

```
      <form id="addCustoInfo" action="saveCustoInfo" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    <label>Customer Type</label> <select name="idCustoType">
                        <s:iterator value="listCustomerType" status="s">
                            <option value='<s:property value="customerTypeId" />'>
                                <s:property value="customerDesc" />
                            </option>
                        </s:iterator>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Customer Name<br></label> <input name="customerInfo.name" type="text" class="required" minlength="8">

                </p>
                <p>
```

The form addCustoInfo.jsp success to display,  but dropdown `idCustoType` didn't display anything whereas `listCustomerType` size more than one. It's maybe caused of active url. In this case, active url is not change even when I click Update Content link.
How can I resolve this. I'd really appreciate your solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Please give more detailed code and explain better where is your problem.